# How to override function in lovcombo in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In lovcombo of ExtJs, the selected entries are separated by semi-colon. What I want is to separate them by a comma. What method should be overridden and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
separator:','
```

at defining the combo